# Can i create zip file (uncompressed) programatically in c# without using any library (without .net zip classes)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, zip

I was looking to understand the structure of the zip file and thinking of creating my own zip library which will be able to zip some files without any compression. Although there are couple of other libraries already exist in .net and third party also which can do that, but I am looking to do it by my own.

I started reading the structure of the zip document :

```
https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html
```

Althought it explains me little bit about the zip structure but did anyone already tried to create zip file from the very scratch (i.e. from bit by bit)

Its not just a question but an open discussion on how to create a zip file bit by bit from your own code in c# (or in other similar language)

Comment: Of course it's possible. Libraries like DotNetZip and SharpZipLib are written in C# so why shouldn't it work? You can use a BinaryWriter to write the individual parts of the header and entries for example. But I think such an open discussion is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: How can i build the header and entries for zip file?

Comment: By reading the documentation of the link you provided and then writing the values using the various methods of the BinaryWriter.

Comment: Is there any need of the crc32, compressed size and uncompressed size while doing that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `GZipStream` class in System.IO.Compression that allows to zip streams using Gzip. As far as I know this is the only class for compression *in the BCL*.

Comment: I don't think the gzip format is the same as the zip format. They both use deflate as the algorithm so a DeflateStream should work to compress individual zip file entries.

Comment: I want to write my custom zip program from scratch without using .net inbuilt zip class.

Comment: @Dirk GZip is not the same as Zip. Zip is an archive format. However, the GZipStream is the only compression class in the BCL

Comment: @Georg: How do i create it manually without using the BCL Compression class. As somehow it doesn't suits my need.

Comment: @ManishRawat In that case, you have to implement a compression algorithm yourself - or you reuse a library as implementing it on your own is a lot of work

Comment: Ok, let me tell you what i want is to allow the user to download the zip file which will get created on the fly and i will stream it without writing it to the disk. In this approach, I need to allow the user be able to do the resumable downloads. So, in order to do that, i want to know how to create the zip file from byte by bytes. Otherwise, I won't able to accomplish this task.